# Visual Studio Code unsaved files location

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code

Does anyone know where VS code saves unsaved files on a Windows machine?

I have found many discussions about this features, but they don't mention where the files are actually saved.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The Microsoft [help file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settings-file-locations) indicates that the settings are stored in the folder:

> Windows - `%APPDATA%\Code\User\`

For me this translated to:

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Code\
```

In this folder I located a `Backups` folder, this folder contained the raw data for my document. This appears to be grouped by date stored as a UNIX timestamp.

[image: VS Code cached document location]

Comment: Thanks! On OS X there is a similar folder in ~/Library/Application Support/Code/Backup where my text files were hiding out.

Comment: What about Linux?

Comment: I don't have a Linux installation to test on unfortunately. However I would guess it is located somewhere in the `/home` folder.

Comment: On my Chromebook Linux, I found it in `~/.config/Code/Backups/...`

Comment: Thank you. I was unable to find the workspace instance my `untitled` document was created through trial and error; using the Backups folder I found it by date in a matter of seconds and my unsaved work was all there!

Comment: For those of readers using Azure Data Studio, the path is very nearly the same. Substitute `azuredatastudio` for `code` in the searched path.

Comment: here are the official docs: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_hot-exit

Comment: you saved my f**king life

Answer (score 33):

For **Linux** users they are found at `~/.config/Code/Backups`.

Comment: `~/.config/Code - OSS/Backups` and `~/.config/Code - Insiders/Backups` for the open source version and the Insiders version, respectively.

Comment: the opensource version folder might have changed: I found it at `~/.config/VSCodium/Backups`

Comment: Found mines in ~/.config/Code/User/History

Comment: @f.cipriani this is for edit history of all files you edit there.

Answer (score 22):

For Visual Studio Code on macOS, these files are found at:

```
~/Library/Application Support/Code/Backups
```

Insiders on macOS:

```
~/Library/Application Support/Code - Insiders/Backups
```

OSS on macOS:

```
~/Library/Application Support/Code - OSS/Backups
```

Comment: awesome, ~/Library/Application\ Support/Code/Backups is the path

Comment: As an example on OSX for Azure Studio (which is based on VS): ~/Library/Application Support/azuredatastudio/Backups/1623786046143/file/6be3cd5e7e4dd5b8f863e42c7ceef3e

Comment: thank you so much! My vscode app kept opening an old file that I had deleted that was a 2gb+ sql file! It kept crashing and I was locked out of my code base until I deleted the backup!

Answer (score 1):

If you use scoop on Windows to manage your (portable) vscode installation, the backup path you're looking for is

```
%USERPROFILE%\scoop\persist\vscode-portable\data\user-data\backups
```

Answer (score 1):

VS Code has a ["Hot Exit" feature](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_hot-exit) that keeps records of files that have unsaved changes when the window is closed so that it can present those unsaved versions the next time it reopens.

Hot Exit file contents are stored under the `Backups` directory under the user data directory. The default user data directory location varies by platform (you can also specify a custom location when opening VS Code via commandline (`--user-data-dir`)). See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settings-file-locations.

- Windows `%APPDATA%\Code`
- macOS `$HOME/Library/Application\ Support/Code`
- Linux `$HOME/.config/Code`
- For VS Code Server, the default user data directory should be `~/.vscode-server/data`

Be warned that the file names are not human-readable, but the file contents should start with a line containing the file's path (unless the file is "Untitled" (has never been saved before)). Tools like grep or ripgrep can help if you have a search string (file name or contents) you can look for.

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails, you may find part or all of your unsaved content in the following location:

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\History
```

I accidentally permanently deleted a file from my disk that didn't have any backup. Even tried those 3rd-party undelete tools, but couldn't find the file. Then I found this post and tried to locate an unsaved version, but there was none. Then just cruising through the directories I found location and therein was my content waiting to be discovered.

Note that VSCode uses hashed file names and there may be lots of subfolders in this location, so a manual find might be tedious. Instead you can open the entire `History` folder in VSCode (`Open Folder` command) and then use global text search to find your file(s). Also note that it stores several copies of each file over time, so u may want to cruise through found files to get the latest version.

Comment: This is the same as the accepted answer

Answer (score -2):

Windows, Visual Studio 2019:

```
%localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\BackupFiles
```

Comment: The OP was specifically asking about VS Code rather than the full Visual Studio.