# Where does Visual Studio Code store unsaved files on macOS?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

[This has been asked regarding Windows](https://superuser.com/q/1225368/23135), but not macOS.

(Yes, there's a comment on that question regarding macOS, but it's a comment and not an answer, so it's likely to be overlooked, and it's on a question about Windows, and to top it all off ***it's wrong***.)

So, for sake of making (the correct version of) this information easy to find:

Where does VS Code store unsaved files on macOS?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It can be found in a subdirectory of

```
~/Library/Application\ Support/Code/Backups
```

Note that the space above has been escaped with a `\` character, so you can copy the path and paste it onto the command line.

If you want to put it in quotation marks, then you'll need drop `\` character, and replace `~` with `$HOME`, like so:

```
"$HOME/Library/Application Support/Code/Backups"
```

On my laptop the subdirectory is named with a 13-digit number, inside of which is `/untitled/`. I would guess that the directory above `untitled` probably varies from installation to installation.

Comment: if you are using the VSCodium flavour it is located here: `"$HOME/Library/Application Support/VSCodium/Backups"`

Comment: At that 'Backups' folder location, you can also look at the `workspaces.json` file; it will list the nice directory path for each project directory which corresponds to the "hashed" directory names. If you go into each one of those and run `code .`, it'll bring up your unsaved files directly.

Answer (score 8):

Updated answer in 2022, for MacOS Monterey and VS Code version Version: 1.67.2 (Universal).

The path where I successfully recovered my 'otherwise considered lost in git rebase, uncommitted, unstaged' file is below:

```
~/Library/Application\ Support/Code/User/History
```

To supplement anyone trying to figure out a way to search all files with a specific extension containing one of the keyword you remember, here is the command:

```
find . -name "*.extension" -exec grep whatYouRememberFromFile {} +
```

Or if you remember only the file name, here is a command that list all 'entries.json' files which will contain all history of the file in hash format

```
find . -name "entries.json" -exec grep portion-of-the-file-name {} +
```

Comment: I have both directories... does `History` keep a more detailed running history of changes?  I'm not sure whether to change the accepted answer to yours or leave it as mine ...