# How to recover unsaved file (Visual Studio Code)?

Tags: code, recovery

my VSC crash without saving how to get back the code ?
already tested appdata\roaming\code\backup i dont found the file

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1225368/visual-studio-code-unsaved-files-location

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio Code unsaved files location](https://superuser.com/questions/1225368/visual-studio-code-unsaved-files-location)

Answer (score 9):

You can recover you projects from the VSCode cache.
In Linux it is located under `/home/USER/.config/Code/User/History/` and under Windows it is `/Users/USER/AppData/Roaming/Code/User/History/`.
Each file has a directory and in each directory there are different versions of the same file.

Edit:
You can also just run the command (Ctrl+Shift+P) "Local History: Find Entry to Restore"

Comment: You saved lots of my time. Thank you.

Comment: On macOS, it's at `~/Library/Application Support/Code/User/History`.

Comment: Saved me plenty pain, once in the windows folder with all the randomly named folders I made this bash command to find python files with a phrase I knew was in the file ("bootstrap"), for easy searching.
`grep -rl "bootstrap" ./**/*.py`

Comment: wrong. this is for saved versions of the file. not the latest unsaved version.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have backups, look in the Recycle Bin for possibly finding a deleted
version of the file.

You could also set Windows Explorer to
[show hidden files](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/9168-show-hidden-files-folders-drives-windows-10-a.html)
and look in the folder where the file was last located. You may find there a version
of it with a mangled name.

Look also in the temporary files folder (if in doubt run in the Command Prompt
the command `set TEMP`).